# Thread block on SharedClassURLHelperImpl

Tags: java, websphere

My application deployed on IBM WebSphere 8.5.5.11. After ~30 minutes of work under load the CPU utilization grow up to 99% (there was ~64% before) and 2\3 of threads are stuck on com/ibm/oti/shared/SharedClassURLHelperImpl.According [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.api.70.doc/com.ibm.oti.shared/com/ibm/oti/shared/SharedClassURLHelper.html) article, interface responce for loading and caching classes. But why it gets 99% of CPU? How i can tune this process or where i can get log\information of this thread?

Answer (score 0):

The problem described in [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM82559) ticket №PM82559, to fix it you need to add parameter com.ibm.xml.xlxp.jaxb.opti.level=0 to custom JVM property on each server of cluster.